# Django Admin: disable selection on the change list page

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I disable selection conditionally on the change list page of the Django admin? For example if `obj.published=True` then the object couldn't be selected by user.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer to a [similar question:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15980439/1734806)

Comment: If it possible I prefer use ModelAdmin class and not extending the template.