# how to make a field which gets shown if another field reached a specific value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say we have:

```
class info(models.Model):
info_type = models.ForeignKey(Subject,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

now in django admin page I want `color = models.CharField(max_length=10)`  field  to gets showed under `info_type` only if the selected value by the user in `info_type` is `color` ( so the user can fill the `color` field too).

how can I make that possible?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68015708/edit) your question and add a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you further clarify what you mean by  "gets shown under `info_type` if `info_type == color` in django admin page"?

Comment: you can use javascript

Comment: You can use javascript with admin model. See here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978719/django-admin-show-field-only-if-checkbox-is-false