# Link choicefield to another within the same form django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a problem about the django admin panel. I am making a form (model) and I want there to be a selection field, and when selecting it, it shows new fields.

This form will be used in the django panel, not by a template. Please look at the example image.

[see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Ifp.jpg)

Comment: you will have to look into Javascript/JQuery. see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978719/django-admin-show-field-only-if-checkbox-is-false

Comment: the program that I am making, is only managed through the django administrator, there will be no HTML, CSS, PHP, Javascripts templates. Is there a way to do what I need without relying on those mentioned?